# Backbone.js: How do I force the View to automatically refresh when changing a models collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

So I have a View that looks like this.

```
    //base class
    var SelectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll');
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.addAll);
        },
        addAll: function() {
            this.collection.each(this.addOne);
        },
        events: {
            "change": "changedSelected"
        },
        changedSelected: function() {
            this.selected = $(this.el);
            this.setSelectedId($(this.el).val());
        }

    });

    //my extended view
    var PricingSelectListView = SelectListView.extend({
        addOne: function(item) {
            $(this.el).append(new PricingView({ model: item }).render().el);
        }         
    });
```

I have instantiated the view like this...

```
var products = new ProductPricings();
var pricingsView = new PricingSelectListView({
     el: $("#sel-product"),
     collection: products
});
```

Somewhere else (another views custom method)I have updated the pricing view's collection

```
pricingsView.collection = new ProductPricings(filtered);
```

This does not seen to do anything.

```
pricingsView.render();
```

So now the collection has fewer items but the new view is never rendered or refreshed in the DOM.

**How to I do I 1.) refresh the rendering in the DOM? 2.) Make it automatically refresh the DOM? Do I have to somehow tell it to render when ever the collection changes?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You bound `addOne()` to a `reset` event. When you just replace the `pricingsView.collection` instance then that event is not triggered and `addOne()` is not executed.

Try instead:

```
pricingsView.collection.reset(filtered);
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work since you bind to collection's reset event already:

```
pricingsView.collection.reset(filtered);
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset

You still have tweak your rendering logic to remove old markup from the view when reset happens.

Comment: Thanks. The light bulb is on!